# ParameterizedSparqlString query with parameter

Tags: java, sparql

The following query is used to get the "abstract" property from dbpedia. When i use a specific name like `res:Zeke_Rowe` instead of `?name` it works. I want to pass a value to the `?name` variable. The sparql query is as follows:

```
ParameterizedSparqlString abstractQuery = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
"PREFIX res:  <http://dbpedia.org/resorce/> "
+"PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> "
+"SELECT ?abstract WHERE { "
+"?name dbo:abstract ?abstract. "
+"FILTER (lang(?abstract)='en')}");
```

I've tried this:

```
 abstractQuery.setLiteral("name", "res:Zeke_Rowe");
 Query query = QueryFactory.create(abstractQuery.toString());
```

but it doesn't work and i get `NoSuchElementException`.

I've also tried:

```
 Node node = NodeFactory.createLiteral("res:Zeke_Rowe");
 abstractQuery.setParam("name",node);
 Query query = QueryFactory.create(abstractQuery.toString());
```

unsuccessfully. having the same exception...

both ways it inserts the name `res:Zeke_Rowe` like this: `"res:Zeke_Rowe"` to the sparql query..

Finally, i run the query like this:

```
ResultSetFactory.copyResults(QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql",query).execSelect());
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the full -stack trace or exception.

Answer (score 0):

Subjects in an RDF triple are never a literal, thus, `res:Zeke_Rowe` is **not** a literal, don't know why you always call `setLiteral` resp. `createLiteral`. It is a URI, either prefixed (`res:Zeke_Rowe`) or full (`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Zeke_Rowe`).

```java
abstractQuery.setIri("name", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Zeke_Rowe");
```

or

```java
Node node = NodeFactory.createIRI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Zeke_Rowe");
abstractQuery.setParam("name", node);
```